# React Dynamic Routing + CMS

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'am building a React app against my CMS which provides an API for fetching pages etc. I however have questions on how to do dynamic routing with React Router. I don't know any URLs as the pages is defined in my CMS and can change whenever the user create/rename/delete a page.

So far I've created a wildcard route as such:

```
<Route path="*" component={PageResolver} />
```

Which points to a component which resolves what pages/components to serve. So when I hit the frontpage '/' or say '/brands' the route will go through my PageResolver which calls an API my CMS is outputting. The CMS then responses with what type of page/components to create. For this I've created a small pages object:

```
const pages = {
    'frontpage': FrontPage,
    'standardpage': StandardPage,
    'filterpage': FilterPage
};
```

If I hit the frontpage the CMS will response with a page type of 'frontpage' and I now know what component to render through my PageResolver.

My PageResolver looks like this:

```
class PageResolver extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            page: null
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getPage(this.props);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.getPage(nextProps);
    }

    private getPage(props) {
        const { url } = props.match;

        axios({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/pages',
            params: {
                url
            }
        }).then(({ data }) => {
            this.setState({ page: null });

            if (data[0]) {
                const pageType = data[0].type;

                this.setState(() => ({ page: pages[pageType] }));
            } else {
                this.setState(() => ({ page: NotFound }));
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { page: PageComponent } = this.state;

        return (
            PageComponent ? (
                <PageComponent />
            ) : null
        );
    }
}
```

Is there any official way or atleast a better way to do this. Above code fells abit hacky?